# GraphQL Architecture - Looking for insight

Tags: node.js, mongodb, http, graphql

I have a bit of an architectural question I hope you fine people could shed some light on. At my company we want to utilize graphql, were on the same page about that. But, there are some folks in our organization who insist on having whats called a backend-end-for frontend (BFF from here on out, you can familiarize yourself here if not familiar: http://samnewman.io/patterns/architectural/bff/) for our individual frontends instead of letting the front ends themselves query the graphql server for what they need. They then want to expose REST endpoints for the frontends, where the bff is this interim layer to the graphql server. So it would look like this: Frontend  1 =====>RESt====>BFF for frontend 1=======>graphql. They want that bff to be a restrictive subset of the entirety of the graphql backend. So , my question to you all is kind of two fold. 1. Is this even reasonable given we can restrict queries via authorization and 2. If I have to deal with this, is it entirely doable to make that BFF a graphql service that has the same schemas they had hoped to expose via rest, and have that use graphql as well to aggregate from the "far backend". Graphql is a godsend for clients, so I would love to use it over still constructing http request for endpoints unnecessarily. Im open to any and all advice, even those indicating that what I would prefer is not as ideal as what they are suggesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you want to create an API Proxy in front of your REST services. This is a very popular approach, implemented for example at Xing and Github (as far as I know). This would remove the BFF layer at some point, the only reason to keep it alive is to support legacy clients. This is because this GraphQL proxy **is a better version of the BFF pattern**. [This talk from GraphQL Europe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bIY2SUSEBY0) might be helpful. You might want to spend more time on learning about GraphQL before diving in. One idea could be to build a prototype in Node.js that uses the backend services to create a GraphQL interface. Depending on the size of your application you might want to implement this in a different language (like Scala + Sangria at Xing).

Comment: thank you for the prompt response. This is exactly how I thought about it. But I have some leadership that didn’t see it that way. Thanks for the reference talk as well.

Comment: When I pitched GraphQL I drew some diagrams to show the architecture. Maybe this can also help you out: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dljk8s4xbvxltm5